# Water Dripping From HVAC Furnace PVC

Tags: furnace

I have 2 PVC pipes coming out of my TRANE gas furnace. Today I noticed that one is dripping water from the top. Picture attached. Its a slow drip. What could this be?[image: 1]

Comment: From the top of the pipe, running down the pipe? Is there a drip above the pipe too?

Comment: It could be condesate, but it could be water from the outside world even. Cane we see a picture from the outside too?

Comment: This appears to be a new high efficiency furnace.  One of those pipes brings in cold air from outside for the combustion, and the other returns the warm combustion gasses back outside.  It's conceivable that condensation could form on the cold pipe, but I've never seen one of these in person.

Comment: We need a picture showing what these pipes attach to - both on the furnace and whatever box on the exterior of the house.